# Get the x position in d3

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a kind of scatterplot with the following data.

```
array = [{
    key: "6S",
    values: {3: [{Id: "1234a"}, {Id: "1234b"}]}
  },
  {
    key: "7S",
    values: {5: [{Id: "1534a"}],4: [{Id: "1534a"}]}
  }
]
```

The x axis represents the "key" value ("6S" and "7S" in the array) and the y axis the key from the values ("3", "5", "4"..). x is defined as scalBand and y as scaleLinear. If the key from the values has 2 objects (in our example "3" has 2 objects) I want to add 2 points side by side.

```
view1.selectAll("circle")
        .data(array)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x1(d.key); }) //must return something else
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y1(Object.keys(d.values))})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return height-y1(Object.keys(d.values))});
```

The domain from x is:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
```

from y:

```
y1.domain([0, 200]);
```

Any idea how I could return the x-axis position?

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: @AdityaK I posted

Comment: Where is `view1` defined?

Comment: @AdityaK i posted

Comment: @AdityaK y1(Object.keys(d.values)) is another problem...I think, I need to acces the data values in different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following.

1. Change the structure of the data and create separate data points by splitting the `values`(the values key in your object) into a different array `newArray`.
2. Create an array of the `cx` and `cy` attributes of your circles to check if there are any overlaps. If yes, shift the `cx` of the overlapping circle by say 10px.

Here's the fiddle:

```js
var svgWidth = 1300,
  svgHeight = 600;

var width = 600,
  height = 250;


var margin2 = {
  top: 10,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 40
};


//Create SVG
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

var view1 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "view1")

  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


var array = [{
    key: "6S",
    values: {
      3: [{
        Id: "1234a"
      }, {
        Id: "1234b"
      }]
    }
  },

  {
    key: "7S",
    values: {
      5: [{
        Id: "1534a"
      }],
      4: [{
        Id: "1534a"
      }]
    }
  }
];
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(function(d) {
  if (Object.keys(d.values).length > 1) {
    for (i in Object.keys(d.values)) {
      var val = {}
      val["key"] = d.key
      val['values'] = {}
      val['values'][Object.keys(d.values)[i]] = d.values[Object.keys(d.values)[i]]
      newArray.push(val)
    }
  } else {
    if (d.values[Object.keys(d.values)[0]].length > 1) {
      for (i in d.values[Object.keys(d.values)[0]]) {
        var val = {}
        val["key"] = d.key
        val['values'] = {}
        val['values'][Object.keys(d.values)[0]] = [d.values[Object.keys(d.values)[0]][i]]
        newArray.push(val)
      }
    } else {
      newArray.push(d)
    }
  }
});

var cxList = [];

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.2),
  y1 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis1 = d3.axisBottom(x1),
  yAxis1 = d3.axisLeft(y1);


x1.domain(newArray.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));


y1.domain([0, 10]);

//Add the "points"

view1.selectAll("circle")
  .data(newArray)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "bar2")
  .attr("r", 2.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    if (cxList.indexOf(x1(d.key) + '-' + y1(Object.keys(d.values))) > -1) {
      cxList.push((x1(d.key) + 10) + '-' + y1(Object.keys(d.values)));
      return x1(d.key) + 10;
    } else {
      cxList.push(x1(d.key) + '-' + y1(Object.keys(d.values)));
      return x1(d.key);
    }
  })
  .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y1(Object.keys(d.values))
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y1(Object.keys(d.values))
  });
//Add x Axis & rotate text
view1.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis1)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("x", 2.5)
  .attr("y", 5)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(25)")
  .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<style>
  body {
    font: 11px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .dot {
    stroke: #000;
  }
  
  .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 28px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width='500' height='500'></svg>
</body>
```

The code you provided still has some stuff missing. The `circles` and the `axis` look a little off in my code but should work fine in yours.